# How to fetch the data from list of object which is inside object using jstl

Tags: java, jstl

```
class Object1 {

  private List<Object2> object2;
  private Object3 object3;

  //setter and getter
}

Class Object2{

  private String firstName;

}
```

I am not able to find the solution how to access the value of firstName using jstl.

```
//controller class

@Controller
public class MyController{

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @RequestMapping(value="/" ,Method=RequestedMethod.GET)
    public String Search(@ModelAttribute("requestObject")RequestObject requestObject,ModelMap map)

    Object1 object1=service.getValue();

    map.put("listObject",object1);
    return "jsppage";

}
```

And in servicelayer I set the value in respective object now i want to fetch the value of `listObject` inside my `JSP` page which is build using Spring tags.

Comment: You should be more clear and show code what you have tried so far. Do you want to loop trough the list `object2` from class `Object1` and show the firstName? Do you have a managed bean containing instances of your objects? It seems you should read some (jsf?) tutorials ...

Comment: Yes...but in my project we use jstl and spring tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "listObject" is accessible on the JSP and you have getter methods for the properties:

```
public List<Object2> getObject2() { return object2; }
public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
```

This should list the names:

```
<c:forEach var="obj2" items="${listObject.object2}">
    ${obj2.firstName}<br>
</c:forEach>
```